# CTRL-C terminate in python

Tags: python, cmd

Currently, I have an exe that I need to pass commands to thru python.  The code worked when it was by itself. When I merged that snippet with my final program, it failed to work.

Basically, after the first two files upload using the program `shell_start` (upload is `-f` in the program i'm passing commands to), python decides to skip the final upload at the bottom with the program called `shell_forward`. The final upload of 3 files with the program `shell_forward`, doesn't even work.

So, my main question, if you're confused, is: why is it that when the program `shell_start` finishes uploading the two commands and files, the python shell won't allow me to type anything in it? It acts like a command prompt window that won't let you type anything into it after code is executed.

That is why I feel that a ctrl-c is needed to terminate `shell_start.exe` from the previous process, so python might let me type after it's execution.

Here's the code:

```
import os, time

name = raw_input("Input your name: ")
apn = raw_input("Input apn name: ")
ecid = raw_input("Input ecid name: ")
kernel = raw_input("Input kernel name: ")

os.system('shell_start.exe -f %s'%name)
time.sleep(1)
os.system('shell_start.exe -f %s'%apn)
time.sleep(1)

os.system('shell_forward.exe --imagefile myfile.img --ecid %(x)s --kernel %(y)s '% {"x" : ecid, "y" : kernel})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have better results by replacing the `os.system` calls with [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

> The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to
>   their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This
>   module intends to replace several other, older modules and functions,
>   such as:
>
> ```
> os.system
> os.spawn*
> os.popen*
> popen2.*
> commands.*
> ```
>
> See also [*PEP 324*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/) – PEP proposing the subprocess module

Comment: that worked. I'm still curious why that happens with os.system though.. hmm... possibly a python glitch? I tried using subprocess earlier, but i guess reading up on the different subprocess codes helped :P thanks for the info!

Comment: EDIT: Just combined that modified code snippet with your subprocess suggestion. still doesn't launch the next program..